# NodeJS/Javascript: how to detect an error object return value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that might return some object or might return a custom error object. I am unable to detect error object type.

I have tried constructor.match(/Error/i) or tried to work on Object.keys of prototype but nothing worked. Following is the code?

```
function x() {
    try {
        ...
    } catch {e} {
       let err = new Error('caught error')
       return err
    }
    return someObject
}

//the following gives: TypeError: err.constructor.match is not a function
if (x().constructor.match(/Error/i)) {
   //log error
}
//do something
```

Any ideas how to detect the output error type?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(x()).includes('error')` ??

Comment: `x instanceof Error`

Comment: @JaydipJ: function x () {let err = new Error(); return err}
console.log(JSON.stringify(x()).includes('error')) --> gives false

Comment: "".include() returns true false as per the condition. you could use this in if block

Comment: @JaydipJ: Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if returned object is an `instanceof` Error as follows

```
let y = x();
if(y instanceof Error) {
  // returned object is error
} else {
 //returned object is not error
}
```

Comment: Other options are `if (Error.prototype.isPrototypeOf(y))` or duck-typing like `if (y.stack !== undefined)`

Comment: @thanks Kiril Rogovoy - that works too but the one in the solution is but more readable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> All `Error` instances and instances of non-generic errors inherit from `Error.prototype`. As with all constructor functions, you can use the prototype of the constructor to add properties or methods to all instances created with that constructor.

Standard properties:

- `Error.prototype.constructor`: Specifies the function that created an instance's prototype.
- `Error.prototype.message`: Error message
- `Error.prototype.name`: Error name

```
try {
  throw new Error('Whoops!');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
}
```

Comment: function x () {let err = new Error("err"); return err}
console.log(x().prototype) <-- gives undefined
Did you mean this?

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error